# Simplifing integral to gamma function

Tags: power-series, improper-integrals, gamma-function

Can you please help me to write the following integral with gamma function using the proper change of variables:

$$ I = \int_0^\infty e^{-a \cdot r^{\alpha}-b \cdot r^{2}} \; \cdot r^{c} \; dr $$

With a, b, c and $ \alpha $ are real positive numbers, and $ 2<\alpha<6 $. I tried with $ t = a \cdot r^{\alpha}+b \cdot r^{2} $ , but I can't go so far with it, I can't write " r " as a function of " t ".

If it's not possible, at least I need it in the case when $ \alpha=4 $:

$$ I = \int_0^\infty e^{-a \cdot r^{4}-b \cdot r^{2}} \; \cdot r^{c} \; dr $$

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$
\Gamma (z) = \int_0^\infty  {e^{\, - x} x^{\,z - 1} dx} 
$$
then we can try and transform the exponential function into a series, as in *Kyril*'s answer, but performing first some 
"massaging". So, standing that the given parameters (particularly $a$ and $b$) are positive

$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {
\begin{gathered}
 I\left| {_{\alpha \, < \,2} } \right. = \int_0^\infty  {\exp \left( { - \left( {ar^{\,\alpha }  + br^{\,2} } \right)} \right)^\, r^{\,c} dr}  = \int_0^\infty  {\exp \left( { - ar^{\,\alpha } } \right)\exp \left( { - br^{\,2} } \right)r^{\,c - 1} r\,dr}  =  \hfill \\
= \int_0^\infty  {\exp \left( { - \left( {ar^{\,\alpha }  + br^{\,2} } \right)} \right)^\, r^{\,c} dr}  = \int_0^\infty  {\exp \left( { - ar^{\,\alpha } } \right)\exp \left( { - br^{\,2} } \right)r^{\,c - 1} r\,dr}  =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{1}
{{2bb^{\,\left( {c - 1} \right)/2} }}\int_0^\infty  {\exp \left( { - br^{\,2} } \right)\exp \left( {\, - \frac{a}
{{b^{\alpha /2} }}\left( {br^{\,2} } \right)^{\alpha /2} } \right)\left( {br^{\,2} } \right)^{\,\left( {c - 1} \right)/2} d\left( {br^{\,2} } \right)}  =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{1}
{{2b^{\,\left( {c + 1} \right)/2} }}\int_0^\infty  {e^{\, - x} \exp \left( {\, - \frac{a}
{{b^{\alpha /2} }}x^{\alpha /2} } \right)x^{\,\left( {c - 1} \right)/2} dx}  =  \hfill \\
  \quad \left| {\;\beta  = a/\,b^{\alpha /2} } \right. \hfill \\
   = \frac{1}
{{2b^{\,\left( {c + 1} \right)/2} }}\int_0^\infty  {e^{\, - x} \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} \frac{{\beta ^{\,k} }}
{{k!}}x^{\,\left( {\alpha \,k + c + 1} \right)/2 - 1} } dx}  =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{1}
{{2b^{\,\left( {c + 1} \right)/2} }}\sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} \frac{{\beta ^{\,k} }}
{{k!}}\Gamma \left( {\frac{{\alpha \,k + c + 1}}
{2}} \right)}  =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{1}
{{2b^{\,\left( {c + 1} \right)/2} }}\sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} \beta ^{\,k} \frac{{\Gamma \left( {\frac{{\alpha \,}}
{2}k + \frac{{c + 1}}
{2}} \right)}}
{{\Gamma \left( {k + 1} \right)}}}  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
\tag {1} }$$
To better analyze the above result for convergence, we rewrite it as:
$$
\begin{gathered}
  I\left| {_{\alpha \, < \,2} } \right. = \frac{1}
{{2b^{\,\left( {c + 1} \right)/2} }}\sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} \frac{{\beta ^{\,k} }}
{{k!}}\Gamma \left( {\frac{{\alpha \,k + c + 1}}
{2}} \right)}  =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{1}
{{2b^{\,\left( {c + 1} \right)/2} }}\sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,2k} \frac{{\beta ^{\,2k} }}
{{\left( {2k + 1} \right)!}}\left( {\left( {2k + 1} \right)\Gamma \left( {\frac{{\alpha \,}}
{2}2k + \frac{{c + 1}}
{2}} \right) - \beta \,\Gamma \left( {\frac{{\alpha \,}}
{2}2k + \frac{{c + 1 + \alpha }}
{2}} \right)} \right)}  =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{1}
{{2b^{\,\left( {c + 1} \right)/2} }}\sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k} {\beta ^{\,2k} \frac{{\Gamma \left( {\alpha k + \frac{{c + 1}}
{2}} \right)}}
{{\Gamma \left( {2k + 1} \right)}}\left( {1 - \frac{\beta }
{{\left( {2k + 1} \right)}}\,\frac{{\Gamma \left( {\alpha k + \frac{{c + 1 + \alpha }}
{2}} \right)}}
{{\Gamma \left( {\alpha k + \frac{{c + 1}}
{2}} \right)}}} \right)}  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
which converges for $\alpha < 2$.

However the original integral clearly converges also for $2< \alpha$: in this case we have to invert
the exponential splitting, obtaining
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {
\begin{gathered}
   I\left| {_{2 \, < \,\alpha} } \right. = \int_0^\infty  {\exp \left( { - \left( {ar^{\,\alpha }  + br^{\,2} } \right)} \right)^\, r^{\,c} dr}  = \int_0^\infty  {\exp \left( { - ar^{\,\alpha } } \right)\exp \left( { - br^{\,2} } \right)r^{\,c - \alpha  + 1} r^{\,\alpha  - 1} \,dr}  =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{1}
{{a^{\,\left( {c + 1} \right)/\alpha } \,\alpha }}\int_0^\infty  {\exp \left( { - ar^{\,\alpha } } \right)\exp \left( { - \frac{b}
{{a^{\,2/\alpha } }}\left( {ar^{\,\alpha } } \right)^{\,2/\alpha } } \right)\left( {ar^{\,\alpha } } \right)^{\,\left( {c + 1} \right)/\alpha  - 1} \,d\left( {ar^{\,\alpha } } \right)}  =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{1}
{{a^{\,\left( {c + 1} \right)/\alpha } \,\alpha }}\int_0^\infty  {e^{\, - x} \exp \left( { - \frac{b}
{{a^{\,2/\alpha } }}x^{\,2/\alpha } } \right)x^{\,\left( {c + 1} \right)/\alpha  - 1} \,dx}  =  \hfill \\
  \quad \left| {\;\gamma  = \frac{b}
{{a^{\,2/\alpha } }} = \frac{1}
{{\beta ^{\,2/\alpha } }}} \right. \hfill \\
   = \frac{1}
{{a^{\,\left( {c + 1} \right)/\alpha } \,\alpha }}\int_0^\infty  {e^{\, - x} \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} \frac{{\gamma ^{\,k} }}
{{k!}}x^{\,\left( {2k + c + 1} \right)/\alpha  - 1} } \,dx}  =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{1}
{{a^{\,\left( {c + 1} \right)/\alpha } \,\alpha }}\sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} \frac{{\gamma ^{\,k} }}
{{k!}}\Gamma \left( {\,\frac{{2k + c + 1}}
{\alpha }} \right)}  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
 \tag{2} }$$
which in fact converges for $2< \alpha$.

For $\alpha = 2$ we instead have
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {
\begin{gathered}
  I\left| {_{\alpha \, = \,2} } \right. = \int_0^\infty  {\exp \left( { - \left( {a + b} \right)r^{\,2} } \right)^\, r^{\,c - 1} rdr}  =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{1}
{{2\left( {a + b} \right)^{\,\left( {c + 1} \right)/2} }}\int_0^\infty  {\exp \left( { - \left( {a + b} \right)r^{\,2} } \right)\left( {\left( {a + b} \right)r^{\,2} } \right)^{\,\left( {c + 1} \right)/2 - 1} d\left( {\left( {a + b} \right)r^{\,2} } \right)}  =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{1}
{{2\left( {a + b} \right)^{\,\left( {c + 1} \right)/2} }}\Gamma \left( {\frac{{c + 1}}
{2}} \right) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
 \tag{3} }$$

*---- addendum -----*

For the **case $\alpha = 4$** you can, among other ways, "complete the square":
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {
\begin{gathered}
  I_{\,\alpha \, = \,4}  = \int_{r = 0}^\infty  {\exp \left( { - \left( {ar^{\,4}  + br^{\,2} } \right)} \right)^\, r^{\,c} dr}  =  \hfill \\
   = \int_{r = 0}^\infty  {\exp \left( { - a\left( {r^{\,2}  + \left( {\frac{b}
{{2a}}} \right)} \right)^{\,2}  + \frac{{b^{\,2} }}
{{4a}}} \right)^\, r^{\,c} dr}  =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{1}
{{2\sqrt a ^{\,\frac{{c + 1}}
{2}} }}\exp \left( {\frac{{b^{\,2} }}
{{4a}}} \right)\int_{r = 0}^\infty  {\exp \left( { - \left( {\sqrt a \,r^{\,2}  + \left( {\frac{b}
{{2\sqrt a }}} \right)} \right)^{\,2} } \right)^\, \left( {\sqrt a r^{\,2} } \right)^{\,\frac{{c - 1}}
{2}} d\left( {\sqrt a r^{\,2} } \right)}  =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{1}
{{2\sqrt a ^{\,\frac{{c + 1}}
{2}} }}\exp \left( {\frac{{b^{\,2} }}
{{4a}}} \right)\int_{x = 0}^\infty  {\exp \left( { - \left( {x + \left( {\frac{b}
{{2\sqrt a }}} \right)} \right)^{\,2} } \right)^\, x^{\,\frac{{c - 1}}
{2}} dx}  =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{1}
{{4a^{\,\frac{{c + 1}}
{4}} }}\left( {\Gamma \left( {\frac{{c + 1}}
{4}} \right){}_1F_1 \left( {\frac{{c + 1}}
{4}\;;\;\frac{1}
{2}\;;\;\frac{{b^{\,2} }}
{{4a}}} \right) - \frac{b}
{{\sqrt a }}^\, \;\Gamma \left( {\,\frac{{c + 3}}
{4}} \right)\;{}_1F_1 \left( {\frac{{c + 3}}
{4}\;;\;\frac{3}
{2}\;;\;\frac{{b^{\,2} }}
{{4a}}} \right)} \right) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
 \tag{4} }$$

You obtain the same result if you rewrite the (2) as
$$
\begin{gathered}
  I_{\,2\, < \,\alpha \;}  = \frac{1}
{{a^{\,\left( {c + 1} \right)/\alpha } \,\alpha }}\;\sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} \frac{{\gamma ^{\,k} }}
{{k!}}\Gamma \left( {\,\frac{{2k + c + 1}}
{\alpha }} \right)}  =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{1}
{{a^{\,\left( {c + 1} \right)/\alpha } \,\alpha }}\;\left( {\sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k} {\frac{{\gamma ^{\,2k} }}
{{\left( {2k} \right)!}}\Gamma \left( {\,\frac{{4k + c + 1}}
{\alpha }} \right)}  - \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k} {\frac{{\gamma ^{\,2k + 1} }}
{{\left( {2k + 1} \right)!}}\Gamma \left( {\,\frac{{4k + c + 3}}
{\alpha }} \right)} } \right) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
and note that for $\alpha = 4$, the ratio $t_{k+1}/t_{k}$ among the terms in each sum
is a rational function in $k$, which allows to tranform the sum into a hypergeometric function.

Comment: Thanks Mr Cab, it's more clear than the first response. As we have $ 2<\alpha<6 $, then I take just the 2nd result expressed as follows: $$ I= \frac{1}
{\alpha (a^{\frac{c + 1}{\alpha}})} . \sum_{k=0}^\infty  (-1)^k \frac{1}{k!}  \left( \frac{b}{a^{2/\alpha}} \right)^k . \Gamma ( \frac{2k+c+1}{\alpha} )    $$  \\   I really need, if it's possible, a simple form in the case of $ \alpha= 4 $ ( not $ \alpha= 2 $ ). I did the substitution in your result, but it's not a relevant result, I ask if it is possible to solve the integral by substituting $ \alpha $ in the integral from the begining.

Comment: @adil: so, for $\alpha=4$ I put an addendum in the answer. The best that you can get is an expression with the sum of two *Kummer confluent Hypergeometric*, which you can obtain from the sum in Gamma if only you care to split it in such a way as to get $\Gamma(k+ \cdots/\alpha)$: if $\alpha$ is even then you get the linear combination of $\alpha/2$ Kummer's functions. And if $c$ is odd, you can transform them into *erf* function.

Comment: @adil: would like to get a feedback from you on whether the answer was helpful.

Comment: @Mr Cab: Sorry me for the late feedback, and thank you very much for your effort. For sure it's useful, but I think that I need to do some approximation in order to get a more simple form without the infinite sum, if it's not possiple I keep it with integral form, I think I can plot it directly with Matlab. Many thanks again.

Comment: @adil: seems to understand that you are looking for a computational method, more than for an analytical formulation. Most math SW can handle Hypergeometric and Erf , otherwise sure you can keep the integral form since the exp is rapidly decaying, in case developing it into a series.

Answer (score 0):

Let $r^{2}=x$, then $dx=2rdr$ then
$$I=2\int_{\mathbb{R}^{+}}x^{\frac{c-1}{2}}e^{-ax^{2}-bx}dx$$
Let $\xi=\sqrt{a}x+\frac{b}{2\sqrt{a}}$, then
$$I=\frac{2}{\sqrt{a}}e^{-\frac{b^{2}}{2a}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{+}}{\Big(\frac{\xi}{\sqrt{a}}-\frac{b}{2a}\Big)^{\frac{c-1}{2}}}e^{-\xi^{2}}d\xi=$$
Now if $c=2l+1$ where $l\in\mathbb{N}$:
$$\Big(\frac{\xi}{\sqrt{a}}-\frac{b}{2a}\Big)^{l}=\sum_{k=0}^{l}\frac{l!(-1)^{k}}{k!(l-k)!}\Big(\frac{\xi}{\sqrt{a}}\Big)^{l-k}\Big(\frac{b}{2a}\Big)^{k}$$
And
$$I=\frac{2}{\sqrt{a}}e^{-\frac{b^{2}}{2a}}\sum_{k=0}^{l}\frac{l!(-1)^{k}}{k!(l-k)!}\Big(\frac{b}{2a}\Big)^{k}\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\Big)^{l-k}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{+}}\xi^{l-k}e^{-\xi^{2}}d\xi=$$
$$=\frac{2}{\sqrt{a}}e^{-\frac{b^{2}}{2a}}\sum_{k=0}^{l}\frac{l!(-1)^{k}}{k!(l-k)!}\Big(\frac{b}{2a}\Big)^{k}\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\Big)^{l-k}\frac{\Gamma\big(\frac{l-k+1}{2}\big)}{2}$$
Otherwise
$$\Big(\frac{\xi}{\sqrt{a}}-\frac{b}{2a}\Big)^{\frac{c-1}{2}}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\big(\frac{c-1}{2}\big)_{k}(-1)^{k}}{k!}\Big(\frac{\xi}{\sqrt{a}}\Big)^{\frac{c-1}{2}-k}\Big(\frac{b}{2a}\Big)^{k}$$
and
$$I=\frac{2}{\sqrt{a}}e^{-\frac{b^{2}}{2a}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\big(\frac{c-1}{2}\big)_{k}(-1)^{k}}{k!}\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\Big)^{\frac{c-1}{2}-k}\Big(\frac{b}{2a}\Big)^{k}\frac{\Gamma\Big(\frac{c+1-2k}{4}\Big)}{2}$$
Here you may have the convergence issues...

Comment: I fail to see how this is a simplification in the *slightest*. In my eyes, you just took a simple integral and turned it into a longer, harder, and uglier summation. Nevertheless, I would love to be corrected.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr Kiryl, but it's not relevant. I thought that it's possible to write the integral as a gamma function without using summation.